# Best Way to add custom http headers in a Custom State Provider on API Platform

Tags: php, http-headers, api-platform.com

I work with CustomStateProviders on API Platform to decorate the return DTO ("Representation") in that way, I like it (hide some fields,...)

I use the standard ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\State\CollectionProvider for filtering, pagination,... and return a JSON-Object:

---cut---

```
namespace App\State;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Doctrine\Orm\State\CollectionProvider;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use App\Dto\ClientRepresentation;

class ClientCollectionProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    private CollectionProvider $collectionProvider;
    public function __construct(CollectionProvider $collectionProvider)
    {
        $this->collectionProvider = $collectionProvider;
    }

    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        $origResult = $this->collectionProvider->provide($operation, $uriVariables, $context);
        header("Pagination-Pages: ".$origResult->getLastPage());
        header("Pagination-Count: ".$origResult->getTotalItems());
        header("Pagination-Limit: ".$origResult->getItemsPerPage());
        return array_map(
            fn($client): ClientRepresentation => ClientRepresentation::fromClient($client),
            iterator_to_array($origResult->getIterator())
        );
    }

}
```

---cut---

As anyone can read, i add standard "header" php function to return the total number of pages ("Paginaton-Pages") total number of items ("Pagination-Items") and currently configured max Items Per Page ("Pagination-Limit").

It works.

But for me, it looks not good.
Is there a better way to set a custom header within a CustomStateProvider on API Platform?

https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/1548 << To add EventSubscriberInterface as shown in norkunas answer at very top might work, but for me it is "similar bad" as my attempt by using the standard php header-function.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve that.

Now that you are using json-ld, I assume that you also use hydra. I would recommend to add "pseudo" hydra properties by decorating api platform's hydra collection normalizer. In this decorator you can also inject your collection provider to retrieve the pagination numbers and add it to the response. See
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data

If you really want to stick to headers, you could add them by creating an eventsubscriber and subscribe to the kernel.response event.    Also here you can inject your collection provider. From the event you can get the response and add your headers. See https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/

PS: you don't need a custom state provider to hide some properties in the response. You can simply use serializer groups to achieve that.